# Is the bytecode that was generated by the compiler will be interepreted by EVM into a machine code?

Tags: evm, compiler, architecture

I am relatively new to Ethereum. After the compiler generate the bytecode, the EVM will interpret this code and convert it to machine code that will run on my CPU or it will transfer this machine code to other nodes?

I am somehow confused with how the structure works in general. So will it interpret the bytecode into machine code and run it on my CPU as well as transfer this machine code to other full nodes to generate the PoW algorithm?

If you can please help me with an example such as deploying a contract. The solc converts it to bytecode and then the bytecode goes to the EVM software on my computer and then interpreted to machine code which will run on my CPU?

Can you help me with resources, please?

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a contract locally and that is perfectly fine for development, for example using ganache. For production you need to deploy the contract to the blockchain, you could using a testnet like ropsten, rinkeby, goerli before deploying to mainnet.

The deployment initializes the contract and assign to it an ethereum address as output. The deployment transaction is sent to the miners that will execute the contract's constructor. The miners will store the result in the blockchain so any other network node will have access to the contract.